# Spring-Kafka ReplyingKafkaTemplate logs full details instead of metadata only when reply times out

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using ReplyingKafkaTemplate to get a synchronous response. When this times out waiting on a response, the entire payload is logged instead of only the metadata, though I have set the option to only log metadata. I am using spring boot 2.6.2, spring-kafka 2.8.1.

What am I missing to get this to only log metadata?

I have tried setting the spring property in application.properties:

```
spring.kafka.listener.only-log-record-metadata=true
```

I have tried setting it directly on the beans:

```
repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(true);
```

I have tried adding this Customizer class I found here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1659

```
@Component
public class Customizer {

    Customizer(AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?, ?> factory) {
        factory.getContainerProperties().setOnlyLogRecordMetadata(true);
    }
}
```

Regardless of these attempts, the full payload is still being logged when the reply times out.

Answer (score 2):

`ProducerRecord`s are logged directly by the template, not the container (which logs `ConsumerRecord`s).

We don't currently have a utility for `ProducerRecords`.

I opened an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2132

Comment: It's hard to see how useful this would be, though, given that all we would have is the topic and (optionally) a partition.

Comment: I'm fine with not logging anything if there's a way to turn it off. My problem is there could be PHI in my log file when a timeout happens. Is there a way to turn it off completely?

Comment: If you are using the `ProducerRecord` variants of `sendAndReceive()`, you could subclass `ProducerRecord` and override the `toString()` method; if you are using the `Message<?>` variants, you would have to subclass the `MessagingMessageConverter` to create your overridden `ProducerRecord`.

To turn it off completely, you could disable logging for the RKT - set the log level to OFF for that task.